# I am trying to find the distance between the two letters in C (using characters)

Tags: c

this is as far I can go

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char a, b;
    int z, abs(inx);

    printf("Enter two English Alphabets: ");

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

        if (abs(a-b) == 0)
            printf("\n.\n");
        else
            printf("\nPlease enter a English alphabet.\n");
        z=abs(a-b); 
        printf("\nThe distance between the characters is  = %d",z);
        return 0;
    }
```

but it keeps returning 0

and I assume the ascii values are automatically stored, but I do not know what is going on.

Comment: What is `int z, abs(inx);`? This looks like you are declaring the function `abs` instead of using the one in stdlib.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

Change this statement like below.

```
scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `%d` in your printf to `%c`.  `%d` expects an int value, `%c` is a char.

You can also drop the `abs(inx)`  in your `int` declaration, as you don't need it, and don't use it.